# Apache NiFi: FlowFileHandlingException when transfer FlowFile in custom processor

Tags: java, etl, apache-nifi

I doing data ingestion from remote API service for different time ranges in my **custom NiFi Processor**.

I have time ranges global counter which updates with each iteration (I'm using Timer driven scheduling strategy).

When the counter is greater than the maximum value, I want to transfer just **FlowFile** from request (`session.get()`) with **SUCCESS** relationship, i.e. without performing additional logic:

```
session.transfer(requestFlowFile, SUCCESS);
```

I undestand that I can't stop or pause processor when time ranges collection is over. So I trying to use the above approach as a solution.

All iterations going fine until the counter has become greater than the maximum and processor trying to transfer **FlowFile** from request (`session.get()`)

So I having this Exception:

failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=459e615b-0ff5-424f-aac7-f95d364cdc13,claim=,offset=0,name=99628180019265,size=0] is not known in this session

What's wrong here? Or may be another approach?

Comment: Can Anybody help me on below issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116184/org-apache-nifi-processor-exception-flowfilehandlingexception-is-not-known-in-t

Answer (score 4):

That error means the flow file being passed to session.transfer() came from a different session. You can only call transfer() on the same session from which you called get().

Answer (score 1):

if it's a custom processor -  just do not do `session.get()` and skip this execution without transferring anything.

or if you need incoming file to take a decision you can get it, do some checks, and rollback the current session with penalize `rollback(true)`, so the file(s) you get will stay in the incoming queue during `Penalty Duration` processor parameter without thiggering rocessor to run.

or you can do `session.get(`[FlowFileFilter](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/FlowFileFilter.java)`)` to get  from incoming queue only files that matches your logic