# org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: is not known in this session) in <script> at line number 32

Tags: apache-nifi, jython, apache-nifi-registry, flowfile

I have written a python script to just compare to strings and putting attribute in the flowfile.
But while handling exceptions, I am getting below error always and my flowfile is stuck in the queue with ExecuteScript Processor with below exception:

2020-02-07 18:15:26,049 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=0fdb3d0f-b361-3b31-faf8-fce2dc707591] ExecuteScript[id=0fdb3d0f-b361-3b31-faf8-fce2dc707591] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=e263f921-8cf3-4bd0-8190-0b3864cc3e78,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1581055293097-1, container=default, section=1], offset=416137, length=1236],offset=0,name=name=test_1/test_2/my_entity/rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child/dd_rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child_1027102c-f97a-11aad-bpo7-bd9840e139df000.csv[image],size=1236] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=22]) in  at line number 32; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=e263f921-8cf3-4bd0-8190-0b3864cc3e78,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1581055293097-1, container=default, section=1], offset=416137, length=1236],offset=0,name=name=test_1/test_2/my_entity/rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child/dd_rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child_1027102c-f97a-11aad-bpo7-bd9840e139df000.csv,size=1236] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=22]) in  at line number 32
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=e263f921-8cf3-4bd0-8190-0b3864cc3e78,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1581055293097-1, container=default, section=1], offset=416137, length=1236],offset=0,name=test_1/test_2/my_entity/rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child/dd_rrp_26_dec_parent_rrp_child_1027102c-f97a-11aad-bpo7-bd9840e139df000.csv,size=1236] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=22]) in  at line number 32
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:239)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

****The below is the script:****

```
enter code here
import java
import os
from java.sql import SQLException
from java.lang import Throwable
flowFile = None
try:
    flowFile = session.get()
    if flowFile != None:
        originalFilname = flowFile.getAttribute('sourceFileName')
        pathFileNameEntity = originalFilname.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
        fileNameEntity = pathFileNameEntity.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        realTimeEntityString = \
            flowFile.getAttribute('my.entity.name')
        for entityName in realTimeEntityString.split(','):
            ename = 'rr_' + entityName.lower()
            if ename == fileNameEntity.lower():
                cEntityName = entityName
                flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,
                        'current.entity.ename', str(cEntityName))
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
            else:
                flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'errorMessage'
                        , 'Issue with RT Entity Names')
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
except Exception, e:

    if flowFile != None:
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'errorMessage',
                str(e))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
except Throwable, e:

    if flowFile != None:
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'errorMessage',
                str(e))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

Can anybody help me understand why it is failing going into except block even if exception did not occur. Is it Syntax error?

Comment: some mistakes in your code. on line 36 you are transferring file to failure even it's `None`. on lines 20 & 24 you are trying to transfer the same file relations in a loop... It's possible to transfer one flow file somewhere only once!

Comment: Hi, The issue on line 36 i'll manage. But I didn't understand your statement "on lines 20 & 24 you are trying to transfer the same file relations in a loop... It's possible to transfer one flow file somewhere only once! ". Actually, I need to transfer the flowfile with attribute 'cEntityName' if the condition is matched, else i  want to send it to failure. The Loop is there because, I am getting list of string with comma seperated and need to compare it with set of a string. That's why I used a for loop.

Comment: you can't transfer the same flow file several times. but you have `session.transfer` in a loop for the same flow file.

Comment: Thanks @dagget. Solved my Issue.